# Page cache size for each pod in Kubernetes

Tags: caching, kubernetes, cloud

Is there a way to control the size of the page cache for each pod in Kubernetes? When I deploy a pod, I want to specify how much memory to use for page caching.

I also want to confirm if currently, when you specify memory for a pod, it uses it for application memory and page cache which can expand or contract based on the memory pressure.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to control the page cache for each pod in Kubernetes.

Currently page cache is counted against the available memory for the pod. You can find more discussion in the open issue here - https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/43916#issuecomment-393228487